# Measuring how "out-of-order" an array is

Tags: algorithm

Given an array of values, I want to find the total "score", where the score of each element is the number of elements with a smaller value that occur before it in the array.

e.g.

```
values: 4 1 3 2 5
scores: 0 0 1 1 4
total score: 6
```

An O(n^2) algorithm is trivial, but I suspect it may be possible to do it in O(nlgn), by sorting the array. Does anyone have any ideas how to do that, or if it's not possible?

Comment: Are your values a permutation of 1,2,...,n?

Comment: If "score" is based on previous smaller elements in input array, wouldn't sorting it change the results?

Comment: @Alin No. @Pavel The sorting is temporary.

Comment: A good blog post w/example python code to perform the inversion count via mergesort is here: https://medium.com/@ssbothwell/counting-inversions-with-merge-sort-4d9910dc95f0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like what you are doing is essentially counting the number of pairs of elements that are in the incorrect relative order (i.e. number of *inversions*). This can be done in O(n*log(n)) by using the same idea as merge sort. As you merge, you just count the number of elements that are in the left list but should have been on the right list (and vice versa).

Answer (score 2):

If the range of your numbers is small enough, the fastest algorithm I can think of is one that uses [Fenwick Trees](http://www.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=binaryIndexedTrees). Essentially just iterate through the list and query the Fenwick Tree for how many elements are before it, then insert the number into the tree. This will answer your question in O(nlogm), where n is the size of your list and m is your largest integer.

If you don't have a reasonable range on your integers (or you want to conserve space) MAK's solution is pretty damn elegant, so use that :)